# AJAX contentType always gives an error

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

So I'm trying to send an array to NodeJS using ajax, the problem is that as soon as I declare

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

it calls the error function, I've been searching around a lot, with no success though.

Checking on the server side, it never even gets the call, just immediately returns an error. If I remove contentType the server gets called, but I can't get the array that I passed in.

Here is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/deposit?steamid=' + steamid,
    data: {arr:items},
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Tradeoffer has been sent");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Failed to call bot, please inform us about this issue by DM'ing us at https://twitter.com/csgobeararms");
    }
});
```

And my server side:

```
app.post('/deposit', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Deposit request recieved, info:');
  console.log('STEAM ID: ' + req.query.steamid);
  console.log('ITEMS: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body.arr));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so `application/json`; The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

If you use **application/json**, you have to use **JSON.stringify()** in order to send JSON object.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a javascript object to json text and stores it in a string.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost:1337/deposit?steamid=' + steamid,
   data: JSON.stringify({arr:items}),
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
   success: function(data) {
      console.log("Tradeoffer has been sent");
   },
   error: function(data) {
       alert("Failed to call bot, please inform us about this issue by DM'ing us at https://twitter.com/csgobeararms");
   }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to hit save *facepalm*. Now I don't get an error, however I still don't get anything on the server side

Comment: A simple typo was the reason nothing happened, but now I get the error again

Comment: I don't know your error, but if you use `contentType:application/json` you have to use `JSON.stringfiy()`.If you not use contentType, you can use `traditional:true` property.

Comment: Have you tested this on your own computer? I would like to know if it's an error on my PC that's causing it